# Render Monaco editor in a separate Window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor

I am developing an application that needs a code editor in a separate window. I want to use monaco editor for this but the editor seems not to work when rendering it in a new window.

Here is a codesandbox with a minimal reproduction example: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-stonebraker-rvleh

If you open the devtools in the new window you can see that the editor markdown gets rendered but it is not visible. I would expect to see the editor also in the new window. Does anyone know why it is not visible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  What file are you trying to edit in the new window?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, using the react component `MonacoEditor` as child within the `NewWindow` component isn't working. Nor using [the create function](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/functions/editor.create.html) with `domElement` in a different window.

This fails because the Monaco editor code uses `instanceof HTMLElement` checks, which only works when the container the editor should render in is in the same window. `instanceof HTMLElement` fails between different window as those have different environments with their own globals, i.e. different `HTMLElement`. So unless the Monaco editor is improved to allow for rendering in another window (like [this](https://github.com/bitmovin/bitmovin-player-ui/issues/261) or [this](https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd/issues/767)) the only option is to trigger editor creation in its own page and load the page in the popup (like [Monaco editor iFrame example](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/samples/browser-amd-iframe)).